# vue form e.target.name.value is undefined

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

My values on my vue js form are blank or undefined when i submit them for some reason. I am trying to log e.target.name.value to the console to check my form values.

Is there an easier way to do this in vue for this setup? I've been trying different methods and I fear i'm trying to homogenize my vanilla js with vue and creating more problems for myself.

my vue data:

```
 new Vue({
            el: '#grocery_list',
            data: {
              selected: null,
              list: [
                {
                  id: 0,
                  category: 'Baked goods',
                  food: ['bread','cookie','butter','powder']
                },
                {
                  id: 1,
                  category: 'meats',
                  food: ['chicken','turkey','beef']
                },
                {
                  id: 2,
                  category: 'fruits',
                  food: ['bannana','apple','pineapple']
                },
                {
                  id: 3,
                  category: 'canned goods',
                  food: ['tomatoes','green beans','corn']
                },
                {
                  id: 4,
                  category: 'veggies',
                  food: ['broccoli','celery','lettuce']
                },
                {
                  id: 5,
                  category: 'pantry',
                  food: ['broom','mop','dried beans']
                },
              ],
              isHidden: true, 
              form: {},
            },

            methods:{

              addItem: function(e){
                console.log(form)
              },

              viewItemsinCat: function(){
                this.isHidden = false
              },

              checkItem: function(){

              }

            }
   })
```

my html

```
    <div class="addItem" id="addItem" @submit.prevent="addItem">
          <form>
              <label for="addItem">Add food item</label>
              <input v-model="form.foodName" type="text" name="foodName"></input>
              <div>
                  <select v-model="form.category" id="food">
                          <option v-for="item in list" name="item">{{item.category}}</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
              <div>
                  <button type="submit">Add Item</button>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vuejs you don't have to use the names or ids to get value of an input all you have is to use `v-model` which is reactive and will update all the form values instantly

check this out

```
<template>
    <div class="addItem" id="addItem" @submit.prevent="addItem">
        <form>
            <label for="addItem">Add food item</label>
            <input v-model="form.foodName" type="text" name="foodName"></input>
            <div>
                <select v-model="form.category" id="food">
                        <option v-for="item in list" name="item">{{item.category}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Add Item</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        form: {}
    }),
    methods: {
        addItem: function(){
            console.log(this.form)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I've edited my code above to include my view data being exported. when I try utilizing your code I get the error that the form is undefined. Do you think this has to do with how I'm exporting 'form'

Comment: my apologies i needed to log this.form not form. Thanks for solving this one for me! :)